# Problem when running Threads in MicroPython with ESP32

Tags: python, microcontroller, python-multithreading, esp32, micropython

I have the following code. I want to run it on an ESP32. The MicroPython is already installed. The problem is that nothing happens. I get no errors but the testThread() method is not called at any time.
I really don't know where the problem lies.

Thank you in advance for your answers.

Code:

```
import _thread
import time

def testThread():

  while True:
    print("Hello from thread")
    time.sleep(2)

_thread.start_new_thread(testThread, ())
```

Comment: That code looks fine. When I enter that at the interactive `>>>` prompt, it runs as expected, printing `Hello from thread` every 2 seconds. I'm running MicroPython v1.14 on an ESP32.

Comment: Okay...Thanks. I get nothing when I run the code. Can the problem come from the ESP32 or from the MicroPython Version?

Comment: What version of micropython is installed on your device?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Same problem with esp32 thread execution - no output from thread function invoking a print statement. Not only that when the thread exited it crashed the esp32.

However, I fortunately had another esp32 and the threaded function worked as expected, output was printed to the repl.

The problem seems to be the latest version of micropython which can be checked by executing `uos.uname()`.

The working `version 1.12.0` while `version 1.14.0` **fails**.

The `uname` output:

```
WORKING: (sysname='esp32', nodename='esp32', release='1.12.0', 
version='v1.12-286-gc5cc64175 on 202
0-03-25', machine='ESP32 module with ESP32')

FAILED: (sysname='esp32', nodename='esp32', release='1.14.0', version='v1.14 
on 2021-02-02', machi
ne='ESP32 module with ESP32')
```

Comment: Wow, that version is almost a year old. Are you sure your 1.14 isn't the unstable release? When you go to download the firmware there are 4 choices and the top 3 are unstable versions. It doesn't seem likely that you need to drop down to 1.12 to make this work. That would mean that threading has been broken for over a year, but it used to work. It doesn't seem realistic that a popular device like the ESP32 would be abandoned in regards to threading for over a year.

Comment: I run also with this version but I don't get any output :-(.